# slice matrix in Numpy (or Theano)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, theano

Is there an optimal way to slice each row of a matrix in Numpy (or Theano) by a stride of N, given start index for each column?

For example, in the matrix A below, starting slice index for each row is given in the first column, and for a row `i`, I want to have `A[i, A[0]:A[0]+stride]`

```
A = [[1,  1,  2,  3,  4, 5, 6],
     [1,  11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
     [3,  22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]]
stride = 2
Desired output:
[[  1.   2.   3.]
 [ 11.  12.  13.]
 [ 24.  25.  26.]]
```

I tried the code below:

```
b = [range(A.shape[0]), A[:, 0]]
c = [range(A.shape[0]), A[:, 0] + stride]
A[b:c]
```

but I got the following error:

```
IndexError: failed to coerce slice entry of type list to integer
```

Comment: The error means that the `b:c` slice notation works with integers, not lists.  So you have to either slice each row and join them, or construct an indexing array that acts on the whole array at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach making use of [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to get those indices for indexing into columns across each row and then using [`NumPy's advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to extract out those elements along each row in a vectorized manner -

```
idx = A[:,0,None] + np.arange(stride+1)
out = A[np.arange(idx.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [273]: A
Out[273]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [ 3, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]])

In [274]: idx = A[:,0,None] + np.arange(stride+1)

In [275]: idx
Out[275]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In [276]: A[np.arange(idx.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
Out[276]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [24, 25, 26]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's optimal, but at least it doesn't throw any errors :)

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,  1,  2,  3,  4, 5, 6],
...                  [1,  11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
...                  [3,  22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]])
>>> stride = 2
>>> numpy.array(map(lambda row: row[row[0]:row[0] + stride + 1], a))
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [24, 25, 26]])
```